# Issue understanding "Referring to Instance Variables" from Apple guide

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to understand [Referring to Instance Variables](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-SW1) from Apple guide but having issue understudying this, Apple Doc says

...When the instance variable belongs to an object that’s not the receiver, the object’s type must be made explicit to the compiler through static typing. In referring to the instance variable of a statically typed object, the structure pointer operator (->) is used.
Suppose, for example, that the Sibling class declares a statically typed object, twin, as an instance variable:

```
@interface Sibling : NSObject
{
     Sibling *twin;
     int gender;
     struct features *appearance;
}
```

As long as the instance variables of the statically typed object are within the scope of the class (as they are here because twin is typed to the same class), a Sibling method can set them directly:

```
- makeIdenticalTwin 
{
    if ( !twin ) 
    {
        twin = [[Sibling alloc] init];
        twin->gender = gender;
        twin->appearance = appearance;
    }
    return twin; 
}
```

Comment: What's your question? What part don't you understand?

Comment: 1. Link the document you are referring to. 2. Please ask a question :)

Comment: oppsy sorry :) ... here is the link

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-SW1

Comment: I am having issue understanding “Referring to Instance Variables” from this Apple guide.

Comment: What are you having a hard time understanding? Add it to your post. Is it what does `->` mean  or how is it referencing another instance of itself or what.

Comment: @Joe I clearly said that I am studying Apple doc and having issue understanding "Referring to Instance Variables", so it means this whole topic, all that you can see is copied from apple doc. Yes -> pointer is also unclear to me. And is this you who negative voted my question? :(

Comment: @SweetJenny not the down voter. The [`->`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) is a dereference operator and comes from `C`, which Objective-C is a proper superset of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to instance variable means, accessing the class instance vars

For example:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
{
   int value;
}

- (void) setValue:(int) val;

@implementation ClassA
- (void) setValue:(int) val
{
   //here you could access class a value variable like this
   value = val;
}
```

Now accessing other classes variables
take for example this class

```
@interface ClassB : ClassA
{
   ClassA aClass;
}

- (void) setValueInAClass:(int) val;

@implementation ClassB
- (void) setValueInAClass:(int) val
{
   //class b could access variables from class a like this
   aClass->value = val;
}
```

Please note that this is very un recommended to do, using the "->" breaks the encapsulation of class a, so dont in 99% of the cases referring to class variables using the "->" is a mistake

Comment: 99% huh? Well 87% of statistics are made up. I am sure accessing iVars is common in `copy` methods.

Comment: yes, you are right since they are protected vars, then the ratio should be much less :)

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith thanks a lot for reply but what you guys are talking about? Please explain me too.

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith you are saying -> is not recommended but why its referred in apple doc.

Comment: It is possible, and as @Joe there are places where is recommended, but in the normal cases, no it is not